# broadcaster permission for android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-broadcastreceiver

I recently did a code scan on my Android source code using HPFortify service. They reported security vulnerability regarding one of the broadcast receivers. They suggested to use the broadcaster permission to reduce the attack vector. This way you are restricting broadcaster, otherwise any malicious application can send the intent and broadcast receiver will process it.

Here is a my actual code:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.xyz.core.util.ConnectionChangeReceiver"
    android:label="NetworkConnection">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

HPfortify recommends that I should be using something like this:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.xyz.core.util.ConnectionChangeReceiver"
        android:permission="SOME-PERMISSION"
        android:label="NetworkConnection">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I tried to look into the source code and documentation but I am not able to find the right broadcaster permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own permission, which makes it impossible to call your receiver unless the caller has the same permission. This is useful for cooperating applications.

Here is the description of the permission tag in the Android Manifest:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

What you can do is something like:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.xyz.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.xyz.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION" />

<receiver
    android:name="com.xyz.core.util.ConnectionChangeReceiver"
    android:permission="com.xyz.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION"
    android:label="NetworkConnection">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: thanks for providing your answer. `android.net.con.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` is sent by the system so this permission thing will not work because system will not have same permission right?

Comment: It should work if you use ``signatureOrSystem`` as ``protectionLevel``.

Comment: I will use that. I was also thinking to use the exported value as `false`. I have used with similar kind of broadcast receiver and it did work. That is also another way of reducing the attach vector.

Comment: I doubt that would work with a system-triggered receiver. The default value for exported is ``true`` for a reason. As far as I know if you set it to ``false`` then nothing else can trigger it except your own app.

Comment: I tested it with one of the broadcast receiver `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` and it did work. I am not sure how it is implemented but I can try with other broadcast receiver.

Comment: OK, I guess we will see if it works or not. Maybe it works with some special intents. I haven't tried it, just read the documentation for the flag and this was how I interpreted it.